# Задержка с обновлением view

Tags: android

Грубо говоря на экране имеем 2 вьюхи. При клике на каждую из них выполняется определенный ресурсоемкий код, часть из которого обрабатывается в тредах (время выполнения около 1 секунды). Беда в том, что при клике, вью должно сразу же скрыться с экрана, но срытие происходит только после того как метод onClick завершается. Получается как бы зависание, оно само меня устраивает, не устраивает только то что вью сразу не пропадает. Логи показали, что свойство выставляется, но обновление экрана по каким то причинам не происходит. Поставил invalidate(), но это не принесло успеха. Что делаю не так?
Логи:

```
view is visible true
view is visible false
//задержка примерно секунда, вью видна
onClick is finished
//вью исчезает с экрана
```

Код:

```
 private class OnClicker implements OnClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Logger.d("view is visible", view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            view.invalidate();
            Logger.d("view is visible", _listMenu.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);
            switch (view.getId())
            {
                case R.id.view1:
                    run1();
                    break;
                case R.id.view2:
                    run2();
                    break; 
            }
            Logger.d("onClick is finished");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Покажите, что из себя представляют run1 или run2, хотя бы в общих чертах. Складывается стойкое ощущение, что они всё же выполняются в UI потоке, несмотря на то, что в начале поста вы утверждаете другое.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что методы `run1` `run2` выполняются порядка 1 секунды?

Comment: falstaf, там идет работа с базой. Суть не в этом. Пусть даже последующие действия не в тредах. Как я понимаю, вью должно обновиться раньше нежели вызовется один из этих методов.

KoVadim да.

Comment: пока не завершиться метод onClick, ничего не будет обновляться. Выносите код в AsyncTask. Костылей, вроде делфовского Application.ProcessMessages; я не видел. Если Ваш код будет выполнятся более 5 секунд - получите ANR - приложение не отзывается + кучу мыслей от пользователей.

Comment: оно лишь ставит в очередь запрос на обновление. А выполнит его только по выходу с текущего метода.

Comment: есть ли какая нибудь возможность принудительно обновить?

Comment: может быть и есть, но это будет очень сложно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`View.setVisibility` лишь обновляет флаги `view` и, если необходимо, флаги `background drawable (Drawable.setVisible)`. Ничего более. На следующей итерации отрисовки эти изменения флагов будут учтены, но вы не отпускаете `UI` поток для этого, следовательно, все изменения вступят в силу лишь по окончании `run1/run2`.

Comment: я думал это решается view.invalidate();

Comment: View.invalidate в итоге сводится к вызовам ViewParent.invalidateChild() и сопутствующим, который, в свою очередь, помечают указанную область как "грязную" (dirty), т.е. требующую перерисовку. Фактическое обновление этой области произойдёт чуть позже, а точнее - в render loop, когда вы отпустите UI поток.

Comment: поможет, но public void postInvalidate (), и юзать его надо из из другого потока, как сколлТу

Comment: Спасибо всем, буду разбираться с кодом в потоках тогда.

Comment: View.postInvalidate() лишь пошлёт нужное сообщение в Handler потока, а разберёт он это сообщение и обработает опять-таки, когда до него дойдёт очередь. Т.е., в данном случае, когда закончится выполнение run1/run2. Единственное правильное решение - не задерживать UI поток ни при каких обстоятельствах. Иначе - беда с отзывчивостью, юзабилити и, как следствие, средним баллом в гуглоплэй.